# git: How to move changes to a new file before merging the branch?

Tags: git, file, merge, copy

I wanted to do some improvements to a piece of code I've written earlier. So I created a new git branch and changed what I wanted to change. Now that the changes are complete, I find that my new version is not necessarily better but just different in the first place. Hence, I think it might be better not to simply merge the branches and change the original file by doing so.
Instead, I'd like to create a copy of the file that contains the new features while the original file remains untouched.
(My work is kind of a research work, so I'd like to compare both versions in action later.)

One obvious way of doing that of course is to check out the master branch, copy the whole content of the original file to the clipboard, check out the feature branch again and paste everything to a new file before doing the merge.

BUT I always like to learn new stuff and my method looks a little neandertaler-ish to me, if you know what I mean...
So my question is: Is there a way to make git do this for me (while doing the merge, maybe).

Thank you! :)

Comment: Much of the point of Git is to be able to go back to any version seamlessly, without having to keep around several versions of the same file. As long as you have good commit messages, you can check out the old version later and run them side by side whenever you like. This does take a little getting used to, but I think it's worth it to keep your repository clean (and thus easy to understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just leave `feature` alone and go back to `master`. It's not neccessary to merge `feature` to `master` before you are sure the update is okay. So now you have both the origin file and the updated, tracked by two different branches.

Assume the file's path is `foo/bar.txt`. Now you are on `master`. If you want to have `feature` version in the same folder, maybe just for comparison. You could simply run `git cat-file -p feature:foo/bar.txt > feature_bar.txt`. The same way, if you are now on `feature` and want to get `master` version, run `git cat-file -p master:foo/bar.txt > master_bar.txt`.

Git of a newer version supports the worktree feature, that we can checkout different revisions into different work trees. If now you are on `master`, you could run `git worktree add <another_path> feature` to checkout `feature`'s files into `<another_path>`. You could manipulate `master` in the current work tree, and `feature` in `<another_path>`, so you don't have to switch branches back and forth. Instead, open two shell windows, one for `master` and the other for `feature`, so you don't have to switch folders back and forth either.

Comment: @Turysaz p.s. `<commit>:foo/bar.txt` is a more generic way to reference a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp file file.new
git checkout file
```

This should allow you copy the file to a new one, and retain the original file.